# How to get information out of netstat's results

Tags: networking, server, netstat

I wanted to know the servers behind my connections and with a browser closed this is the result of my `netstat` command.

```
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx     ec2-54-229-105-92:https TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx     bud02s21-in-f170.:https TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx     ec2-54-229-110-20:https TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx     muc03s13-in-f14.1:https TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx     bud02s22-in-f206.:https TIME_WAIT
```

I searched for `bud02s21-in-f10` and turned out that this is a google server.

Could you please explain the purpose of these connections?

Is there any way to get information about these servers? I tried `geoiplookup` but didnt get any useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: No

It doesn't really help much if you do know stuff about it, in the current position.

If you would've gotten DDOSed you might be worried about it.

Netstat is there to help you solve network issues that arise on local server services.

Most you could do is use nmap, scan for protocols and see different attributes, but good security practices might be in place and thus all the protocols be scrambled AND behind a firewall.